# swagger-annotations @Schema does not provide a means to define properties

Tags: file-upload, swagger, multipartform-data, openapi

I am using `swagger-annotations:2.1.1`.

According to [swagger.io specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) a configuration for a multipart file-upload would be:

```
"requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "file_a": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary"
                  },
                  "file_b": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

This - in fact - would work and show two file upload buttons in swagger-ui and send a correct multipart-request to my server.

I cannot find any property in `@Schema` annotation to provide a `properties` section. What I came up with so far is:

```java
@Operation(
            requestBody = @RequestBody(
                    content = @Content(
                            mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                            schema = @Schema(
                                    type = "object"
                                    // -> properties[] is missing !!!
                            )
                    ))
    )
```

Why does `@Schema` not provide any means to add the `properties` section?

Best,
-Stefan